# Is there a limit to maximum or minimum wavelength which can be measured using double slit experiment?

Tags: waves, double-slit-experiment

Please correct me if I am wrong.

In a double slit experiment, in order to measure wavelength,there seems to be a [minimum size of slit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/797190/251814) (e.g hydrogen atom) and on galactic scale there seems to be an interplanetary distances as a limit to the size of the slit.

Waves can be mechanical , quantum mechanical or electromagnetic or gravitational.

My question is : Is there a limit to maximum or minimum wavelength which can be measured using double slit experiment?

Comment: You are basically asking if quantum mechanics stops producing wave effects at some scale. Probably not on practically accessible length and time scales. The limit at the low frequency, long wavelength end is probably being set by the proton decay time scale (which eliminates the slits). That's just not an experiment you will get funding for... there will be no journals to print the result in... they will all have decayed together with the slits. It's basically paint that never dries.

Comment: @FlatterMann Yes. You can frame the question that way also. If we talk about maximum frequency limit then as Anna said in the linked question , we can not create a slit smaller than Hydrogen atom…

Comment: Anna said that? She is a high energy physicist. She knows that we have beautiful scattering data showing the quarks inside of protons.